# How do i increment columns with the indirect function?

Tags: excel

I am having a difficult time attempting to get the column() function to increment correctly.

The numbers i need to pull, will be from various sheets, but they are all starting at K3 and then +8 columns after that. I can get the first column (k3) to show properly but nothing after that.

Here is what i am working with.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!k3")
```

Where does / would the column() function go to achieve my goal, or is there something else i should be trying?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to be able to drag the formula across columns and have it increment from K3 to K11 to K19,  adding 8 for each column into which the formula is dragged?

Comment: yes, but I am looking to drag it across and get the results from K3, S3, aa3....

I should be using the column function right? I thought the column function moved across the sheet, while row moved down...?

Comment: So depending on what you want then something like this `=INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!k" & Column(A:A) + 2")` this will increase the column by 1 for each column into which it is dragged. If you want it to increment by a factor then: `INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!k" & (Column(A:A) *8)+ 2")` which increment by 8.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ADDRESS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89) to supply the text-based cell reference into [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd). A little maths with the [COLUMN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) supplies the 8-column stagger and the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) adds 'fill-down' functionality. The added bonus is that you can incorporate the worksheet name directly into one of the optional parameters.

In B2 as a standard formula,

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(3:3), 11+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*8), 4, 1, $A2))
```

Fill right as necessary.

[image: address_with_indirect]

Note that I have intentionally added a space to the worksheet names in order to demonstrate the ADDRESS function's addition of surrounding 'ticks' (e.g. `'` ) when necessary.